# Delete content stored in an array from a log file in php

Tags: php, mysql, file, centos

I extracted some data from a log file and put it in an array (lets call it `$line_content`). I copied the 1st 15 lines from the array into another array (`$line_content15`). I want to delete/remove these 15 lines from the log file. How should I do it? I tried to use str_replace, like in this code snippet:

```
file_put_contents($filename, str_replace($line_content15 . "\r\n", "",
file_get_contents($filename)));
```

Any input would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: If `$line_content15` is an array you can't concatenate to it. You need to implode it to a string.

Comment: Ah, I see thank you! @user3783243

Answer (score 0):

As @user3783243 commented, I needed to implode the array and use

`array_splice($imploded_content,$initial_line_number,$last_line_number)`;.

In this case,

`$initial_line_number=0` and `$last_line_number=15`.

**Update:**

I also need to change permission for PHP to access and modify the file.

Answer (score 0):

Given that log files often get very large then trying to do this in memory is not a good solution. Also, given that log files are usually part of one's audit trail, they should not be modified. But assuming there is a valid reason.....

```
 function delete_lines($fname, $startline, $endline)
 {
    $tmp=tmpfile();
    $in=fopen($fname, 'r+');
    if (!flock($in, LOCK_EX, $wouldblock) || $wouldblock) {
        trigger_error("Unable to lock file");
        return false;
    }
    for ($x=0; $x<$startline; $x++) {
       fputs($tmp, fgets($in));
    }
    for ($x=0; $x<($endline-$startline); $x++) {
       fgets($in);
    }
    while (!feof($in)) {
       fputs($tmp, fgets($in));
    }
    fseek($tmp,0);
    fseek($in, 0);
    $newsize=0;
    while (!feof($tmp)) {
       $newsize+=fputs($in, fgets($tmp));
    }
    ftruncate($in,$newsize);
    fclose($in);
    fclose($tmp);
    return true;
 }
```

You may want to add additional error handling in the above. This can be implemented with a single open file - but it can become messy quickly.